# unable to use $merge on another remote database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to move documents based on last update time into another remote db.

Currently trying to use $merge to implement the same.

But new database is created on same local connection and not on remote connection.

```
LOCAL_DB_NAME.aggregate([
    { $merge: { into: { db: "REMOTE_DB_NAME", coll:"COLLECTION_NAME"  } }},
]).toArray();




Connection Initialization code:

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://xxx:27017';
const dbName = 'local';

const url2 = 'mongodb://xxx:27017';
const dbName2 = 'remote';

var dbClient,dbClientRemote;

MongoClient.connect(url, async function(err, client) {
  if(err){
    console.log("->", err)
    return
  }
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  dbClient = client;

  MongoClient.connect(url2, async function(err2, client2) {
    if(err2){
      console.log("->", err2)
      return
    }
    console.log("Connected successfully to server2");

    const db2 = client2.db(dbName2);
    dbClientRemote = client2;

  });
});
```

Comment: How to tell mongodb aggregate about remote db in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can move into `[different DB] collection` only for the same instance (Standalone / Replica set).